# Trying to write a program that sorts just two numbers using only if and else-if statements

Tags: c++, sorting

This program compiles and runs, but gives me some weird output (such as 7089) which is not what I am looking for. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with it and how I can fix this program so that it actually sorts two numbers input by the user?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main(){
int nums[3];
int first, second, third, fourth;
cin >> nums[0] >> nums[1];
if(nums[0] > nums[1]){
    nums[0]=first;
    nums[1]=second;}
else if(numb[0]<numb[1]){
    nums[0]=second;
    nums[1]=first;}
cout << first << second;

system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: first and second are uninitialized variable and contain garbage data. That is what you are getting.

Comment: How does it compile and run without giving you an error on `else if(numb[0]<numb[1]){`? In addition to what bkVnet said, you have suddenly started using values from an array that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Are you messing up the assignments?

The right code should be

```
if(nums[0] > nums[1]){
    first = nums[0];
    second = nums[1];}
else if(numb[0]<numb[1]){
    second = nums[0];
    first = nums[1];}
```

Comment: That was it. Thank you very much! Can you explain the logic on this?

Comment: @BigBoss, You have to read how the assignment `=` operator works. The value of the variable on its right side is assigned to the variable on the left side.